# I need to import mysql 5.1 to 5.5?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql 5.1 database and I need to import into localhost running 5.5. How do I import into 5.5 or downgrade mysql?

Comment: `mysqldump` is your friend.

Comment: When I export my database and try to import to my new 5.5 server I get this error   Error
SQL query:

[...]

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PK ' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Install phpMyAdmin for your 5.1 OS:

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-phpMyAdmin-on-Your-Windows-PC

or

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04

Then login, click on your database, hit export, and export in SQL format (quick is fine). Then import that .sql file into your 5.5 server (after installing phpMyAdmin) by logging in clicking your database and then hit import.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you paste line 1 of your import file?

Comment: my DB was super large. I had to export groups of tables, import groups of tables, and then verify all tables were accounted for. DB 5.5 appears to be working fine. Thank you